# How to setup undo/redo system during runtime with Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, system, undo-redo

I'm trying to set up an undo/redo system during runtime and couldn't get my code to work correctly. I have created an undo button, but when I moved my game object and press the undo button, the game object doesn't go back to its original states.

I just wanted to be able to have the end-user undo /redo his lastest action **during runtime** and **not during Editor mode**.  I have made several attempts and have tried many different scripts but haven't made any progress.  Any suggestions?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class undoit : MonoBehaviour
{
    public class setting
    {
        public GameObject Obj;
        public Vector3 Pos;
        public Quaternion Rot;
        public bool Deleted;

        public void Restore()
        {
            Obj.transform.position = Pos;
            Obj.transform.rotation = Rot;
            Obj.SetActive(Deleted);
        }
        public setting(GameObject g)
        {
            Obj = g;
            Pos = g.transform.position;
            Rot = g.transform.rotation;
            Deleted = g.activeSelf;
        }
    }
    public List<setting> UndoList;

    public void AddUndo(GameObject g)
    {
        setting s = new setting(g);
        UndoList.Add(s);
    }
    public void Undo()
    {
        if (UndoList.Count > 0)
        {
            UndoList[UndoList.Count - 1].Restore();
            UndoList.RemoveAt(UndoList.Count - 1);
        }
    }
    void Start()
    {
        UndoList = new List<setting>();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you are memorising with each step all the things that changed?

Comment: Right now, I just wanted to change one step and see if the code is working.

Comment: well, 1 or many, if you arent remembering all the states of things before the change, and what to put back... 1 or many is irrelevant

Comment: I'm assuming my code is too simple to work with undo...

Comment: I doubt it, it doesnt matter how complex or simple it is, you need to remember all the before, and return to it.. its not exactly clear what you change only that you store certain info, there maybe more to it than that.. nor have you explained in what way it doesnt work

Comment: I'm just moving my game object to another location and was hoping the undo button will have the game object go back to its original location.  There isn't any rotation or destruction to the game object.

Comment: so how is it not working when you try put it back where it came from

Comment: When I press the undo button, the game object doesn't move.  It just stays there.  I'm assuming it must be a coding issue or a connection.

Comment: well some debugging would probably clear up your confusion, do these objects have rigid bodies? navmesh agents?

Comment: No, it doesn't have rigid bodies or navmesh.  It just game object I can drag across the screen.

Comment: check the values being added, check whats being picked up on the way back

Comment: You are calling your addundo before you make the changes right?

Comment: In general instead of a List you should use two Stacks, UndoStack and RedoStack. a) Undo: UndoStack.Pop, undo this action, RedoStack.Push b) Redo: RedoStack.Pop, redo the action, UndoStack.Push c) new Action: Clear the RedoStack, do the action, UndoStack.Push

Comment: Yes, I'm calling my addundo before making the changes.

Comment: Ok, I will look into changing the stacks and see if that will make a difference.

Comment: BTW, if setup an Undo: UndoStack.Pop, how should I write up the code?  I have never written a stack.push or stack.pop before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need something you can store the relevant data to like e.g.

```
public struct ObjectState
{
    // The transform this data belongs to
    private Transform transform;

    private Vector3 localPosition;
    private Quaternion localRotation;
    private Vector3 localScale;

    private bool active;

    public ObjectState (GameObject obj)
    {
        transform = obj.transform;
        localPosition = transform.localPosition;
        localRotation = transform.localRotation;
        localScale = transform.localScale;

        active = obj.activeSelf;
    }

    public void Apply()
    {
        transform.localPosition = localPosition;
        transform.localRotation = localRotation;
        transform.localScale = localScale;

        transform.gameObject.SetActive(active);
    }
}
```

Next I would use a wrapper class to store undo able changes like

```
public struct UndoableChange
{
    private ObjectState _before;
    private ObjectState _after;

    public UndoableChange (ObjectState before, ObjectState after)
    {
        _before = before;
        _after = after;
    }

    public void Undo()
    {
        _before.Apply();
    }   

    public void Redo()
    {
        _after.Apply();
    }     
}
```

Or in case you need it for my objects at once you could use lists e.g. something like

```
public struct UndoableChange
{
    private List<ObjectState> _before;
    private List<ObjectState> _after;

    public UndoableChange (List<ObjectState> before, List<ObjectState> after)
    {
        _before = before;
        _after = after;
    }

    public void Undo()
    {
        foreach(var state in _before)
        {
            state.Apply();
        }
    }   

    public void Redo()
    {
        foreach(var state in _after)
        {
            state.Apply();
        }
    }     
}
```

Then for the controller I would use two [`Stack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1). A `Stack` is "last in - first out" so exactly what you need. You add new entries using `Push` and by using `Pop` you retrieve the last added element and at the same time remove it from the stack. So it would look like

```
public static class UndoRedo
{
    private static Stack<UndoableChange> undoStack = new Stack<UndoableChange>();
    private static Stack<UndoableChange> redoStack = new Stack<UndoableChange>();

    public static void Undo()
    {
        if(undoStack.Count == 0) return;

        var lastAction = undoStack.Pop();

        lastAction.Undo();

        redoStack.Push(lastAction);
    }

    public static void Redo()
    {
        if(redoStack.Count == 0) return;

        var lastAction = redoStack.Pop();

        lastAction.Redo();

        undoStack.Push(lastAction);
    }

    public static void AddAction(UndoableChange action)
    {
        redoStack.Clear();

        undoStack.Push(action);
    }
}
```

I dont know how exactly your user interacts with the objects but you now would always do something like

```
// at some point store the initial values
var before = new ObjectState (selectedGameObject);

//TODO Apply all your changes to the selected object 

// get the new values
var after = new ObjectState (selectedGameObject);

// Log to the history
UndoRedo.AddAction(new UndoableChange(before, after));
```

or use lists for all selected objects accordingly e.g. simply using `Linq`

```
using System.Linq;

...

var before = selectedGameObjects.Select(obj => new ObjectState(obj)).ToList();

//TODO Apply all your changes to all the selected objects 

var after = selectedGameObjects.Select(obj => new ObjectState(obj)).ToList();

UndoRedo.AddAction(new UndoableChange(before, after));
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: Wow!  Thank you for your response.  I really appreciate the explanation and coding on your part.  I will see if I can implement your coding into my script.

Comment: I have a few errors in the codes.  One is for var lastAction.*Undo*();.  The other is public *UndoableChange*(ObjectState before, ObjectState after). and finally UndoRedo.AddAction(new UndoableChange(before, after));.

Comment: just updated the answer .. there was a `class` missing for `pubic class ObjectState` and I the methods the fields had to start with `_` ;) as said I'm only on the pH so sometimes I have some typos :'D

Comment: For some reason, I'm still getting an error on UndoRedo.AddAction(new UndoableChange(before, after));

Comment: What does it say?

Comment: I'm also getting The contextual keyword 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaration or in script code on the var before and var after.

Comment: Well all the final code blocks of demonstrating the usage will need to be somewhere within a method. Otherwise you will need the `before` and `after` as private fields with explicit types yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207785/discussion-between-coder-and-derhugo).

Comment: Ok.  I will look into it.  Again thank you for your help derHugo!